# Scaffolding Oracle Schema with ODP.NET Core into secondary project creates blue arrow "link" files in main project

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I run Scaffold-DbContext using the Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore provider and set the -OutputDir to a folder outside the main project (such as in a secondary "data" project) Visual Studio is creating "shortcut" type files (the icon has a blue arrow) in the main project for every table class created by the scaffolding. Why is it doing this? Is it needed for the entity framework to function? If it is needed can I direct Visual Studio to create them in a sub-folder of the main project?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouFSk.jpg) of the class files made by the scaffolding normally on the bottom and the weird shortcuts it's making at the top.

Comment: have you found why its showing? it is showing to me also.

Comment: Nope I still have no idea why this happens or how to stop it. I just have to go back in after I scaffold and delete them all out of my main project